# PyQt5 set variable to Text-Edit widget via .setPlainText

Tags: python, pyqt5

I built a password-generator with python. It runs fine in the IDLE but whenever I convert the .py file to an .exe, it closes immediately on a machine with no python installed.
So I wanted to build it a GUI, to prevent the closing.

I want to display the generated password, which is saved in a variable, in a Text-Edit widget. 
This is a part of the method which stores it.

```
# Conversion of list to string
        stringpw = ""
        for i in lst:
            stringpw = stringpw + str(i)

        # change positions
        def change_text(stringpw):
            total= []
            for wort in stringpw.split():
                w = list(wort)
                random.shuffle(w)
                total.append("".join(w))

            return " ".join(insgesamt)

        finalPassword = change_text(stringpw)

        return finalPassword
```

I translated it to english, because it's coded in another language, just in case there are mistakes in the code. However the original code runs fine without any problem.

My problem is, that it doesn't show the `finalPassword` in the Text-Edit widget, when I run this (the output field exists and the self.ui referring to it is instantiated earlier):

```
self.ui.output.setPlainText(finalPassword)
```

Is there a possibility to display this variable? Cause normally you can only show a string in the brackets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you use QPlainTextEdit to print the password or lineEdit?
if QPlainTextEdit then you should use `appendPlainText` insted of `setPlainText`